# Simple email sender with NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, web, github

I'm totally new to web development and working with web related concepts and frameworks (IPs, networks, routers, I cringe everytime :D ).

But, thanks to some internship work I have "forced myself" to work with this and thanks to lots of digging on the internet I have managed to develop a super simple app that can send emails if I am under my localhost. But, I have some (many) questions, but first, the files that comprise all of my code:

Package.json file

```json
{
    "name": "email-node",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "nodemailer": "~0.7.1",
        "express": "~4.5.1"
    }
}
```

Index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Node.JS Email application</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>// <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var from,to,subject,text;
        $("#send_email").click(function(){     
            to=$("#to").val();
            subject=$("#subject").val();
            text=$("#content").val();
            $("#message").text("Sending E-mail...Please wait");
            $.get("http://localhost:3000/send",{to:to,subject:subject,text:text},function(data) {
                if(data=="sent") {
                    $("#message").empty().html("Email is been sent at "+to+" . Please check inbox !");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Mailer In Node.JS</h1>
        <input id="to" type="text" placeholder="Enter E-mail ID where you want to send" />
        <input id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Write Subject" />
        <textarea id="content" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Write what you want to send"></textarea>
        <button id="send_email">Send Email</button>
        <span id="message"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js File

```js
var express=require('express');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var app=express();
/*
Here we are configuring our SMTP Server details.
STMP is mail server which is responsible for sending and recieving email.
*/
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "MYGMAIL@gmail.com",
        pass: "MYGMAILPASS"
    }
});
/*------------------SMTP Over-----------------------------*/

/*------------------Routing Started ------------------------*/

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});
app.get('/send',function(req,res){
    var mailOptions={
        to : req.query.to,
        subject : req.query.subject,
        text : req.query.text
    }
    console.log(mailOptions);
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.end("error");
        }else{
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
            res.end("sent");
        }
    });
});

/*--------------------Routing Over----------------------------*/

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Express Started on Port 3000");
});
```

From what I have read here is what I concluded:

Node.js + Express applications always "listens" to incoming connections on port 3000 so that is the value I use.

Ideally, to send stuff from a website instead of my localhost I believe that the problem lies on the index.html file.

Specifically, this line:

```
$.get("http://localhost:3000/send",{to:to,subject:subject,text:text},function(data){
```

where instead of using http://localhost:3000/send I would use something like:

http://bruno-oliveira.github.io:3000/send

I have read countless forums and posts, tried everything from:

```
$.get("/send",{to:to,subject:subject,text:text},function(data){
```

to searching for github servers IP adress range ( https://developer.github.com/v3/meta/ ) to try and use them directly there and nothing seems to work...

The application is supposedly host here:

http://bruno-oliveira.github.io/

Can someone help me?

Best,

Bruno

Comment: You can simply use `$.get("/send",{to:to,subject:subject,text:text},function(data){`

Comment: When you make `AJAX` request, the browser won't allow you to make `cross domain requests` due to restrictions specified in the `Same Origin Policy`.

Comment: As an after thought, I believe `github.io` only hosts static files. So Your server won't be running when you host your application on your github domain. Did you have any success sending email from localhost?

Comment: So basically, using `$.get("/send",{to:to,subject:subject,text:text},function(data){` should work?

If so, what should I write on the `app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Express Started on Port 3000");
});` simply leave it blank?

Because I think I've done it and using it from my github website it gets stuck in the sending email part

Comment: @Maverick, yes, using that code as above, I can send emails from localhost with no problem at all

Comment: Great! `github.io` is not a node hosting platform. So your server won't be reachable if you use `/send` as URL.

Comment: Regarding your other question, if you want to find your current server IP address, you can simply use `var ip = require("ip");
console.dir ( ip.address() );`

Comment: So, bottom line, everything is working except that I need to host my app somewhere else besides github.io? :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84683/discussion-between-bruno-oliveira-and-maverick).

Comment: yes. You can test it out on heroku, nodejitsu, open shift etc. There are many other platforms where you can host. check out OpenShift, I believe they have free version with some restrictions. I am sure you'll be able to test this out there. Also use `/save` as your URL as opposed to other alternatives. :)

Comment: So I should use `/save` where I have `/url`?

Comment: Yes, instead of using something like `http://localhost:3000/send` use `/send`